# 12.04 scan mode does not work

Tags: 12.04

my HP pSC-2400-series device still prints but does not longer scan since I switched to version 12.04.
I had no problem with scanning under 11.10.

When trying to scan the software (Impress or Writer) always crashes or simply nothing happens.

Thanks for a hint !

Answer (score 2):

Use XSANE to scan and Download and install HPLIP directly from the HP OPEN SOURCE website. http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

Click on DOWNLOAD HPLIP. Find the downloaded file and right click on it and select PERMISSIONS. Select MAKE EXECUTABLE. Click OK.

Right click on the file again and select OPEN then EXECUTE. Follow the instuctions.

*Reason it works is mainly because it detects and installs dependencies that the apt-get or software center version won't.

Once you install the driver in this fashion XSANE should pickup your scanner if it's supported.